# For Android O notification, can we adjust size of the notification long-press menu?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

In Android O notification, when you long press the app icon, it will pop up a notification menu (put an example screen shot below). I want to make its length longer so the notification message can be displayed more completely.

Do we currently have a way to do it?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, that is provided by the home screen implementation, not the OS.